# how to make trigger cannot delete table in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

i want to make a trigger in oracle   .

example, I have a table 'test'. and have 8 data  .

i want to, if data in table test under 10 data . the table cannot be delete/drop

```
create or replace trigger lalala
before drop on system.schema
begin
if  count(*) table = <10
then
raise_application_error(-20001,'Table cannot be deleted');
end if;
end;
/
```

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a DDL trigger for a start.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i6061

You'll want a "BEFORE DROP" trigger that performs a count of the number of rows in the table, and raises an error if certain conditions are not met.

I'd suggest starting with a trigger that just raises an error, and then customise it to detect the number of rows in the table first.

Detect the number of rows in the table by declaring a variable and then:

```
select count(*)
into   my_variable
from   my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace trigger tdroptest before drop on schema
  when (ora_dict_obj_name = 'TEST' and 
        ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE' and
        ora_dict_obj_owner = 'SYSTEM'
       )
declare
    c integer;
begin
    select count(*) into c from system.test;
    if (c <= 10) then
      raise_application_error(-20001,'Table cannot be deleted');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe test in select must include schema name. I have edited the answer to include system.test instead of test.

Comment: I have tested the trigger in Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 and it works. Are you sure that your test table is in system schema?.

Comment: yes. in system, i drop the test table. but not works.

Comment: Let's test it. Execute "create table system.test ( a integer );" then create the trigger and check it does not say "created with errors", and then try to execute  "drop table system.test;" (does not insert rows). You must have an error: -20001 Table cannot be deleted.